# Save an imagesc output in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, save

I am using imagesc to get an integral image. However, I only manage to display it and then I have to save it by hand, I can't find a way to save the image from the script with imwrite or imsave. Is it possible at all?

The code:

```
image='C:\image.jpg';
in1= imread((image));
in=rgb2gray(in1);
in_in= cumsum(cumsum(double(in)), 2);
figure, imagesc(in_in);
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try imwrite?

Comment: No errors, the image saved is simply empty

Comment: @George what do you mean empty? 0 bytes file? All white? All black?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use the *print* command. For instance if you are running over multiple images and want to serialize them and save them, you can do something like:

```
% Create a new figure
figure (fig_ct)
% Plot your figure

% save the figure to your working directory
eval(['print -djpeg99 '  num2str(fig_ct)]);
% increment the counter for the next figure
fig_ct = fig_ct+1;
```

where `fig_ct` is just  a counter. If you are interested in saving it in another format different than jpeg take a look at the documentation, you can do tiff, eps, and many more.

Hope this helps

Comment: The function syntax (`print(gcf, '-djpeg99', num2str(fig_ct))`) should (nearly) always be preferred to using `eval`

Comment: Thanks! Will look into changing my scripts to the preferred usage.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your problem may be with the fact that you are saving a double matrix that is not on the range of [0 1]. If you read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html), you'll see that

> If the input array is of class double, and the image is a grayscale or
>   RGB color image, imwrite assumes the dynamic range is [0,1] and
>   automatically scales the data by 255 before writing it to the file as
>   8-bit values.

You can convert it yourself to a supported type (that's logical, uint8, uint16, or double) or get it in the range [0 1] by, for example, dividing it by the max:

```
imwrite (in_in / max (in_in(:)), 'out.jpg');
```

You may still want to further increase the dynamic range of the image you saved. For example, subtract the mininum before dividing by the max.

```
in_in = in_in - min (in_in(:));
in_in = in_in / max (in_in(:));
imwrite (in_in, 'out.jpg');
```

If you want exactly what `imagesc` displays

> The `imagesc` function scales image data to the full range of the current colormap.

I don't know what exactly does it mean exactly but call imagesc requesting with 1 variable, and inspect the image handle to see the colormap and pass it to `imwrite()`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and most of all for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a very new programmer, so apologies in advance if this isn't very helpful, but I just had the same problem and managed to figure it out. I used uint8 to convert it like this:

```
imwrite(uint8(in_in), 'in_in.jpg', 'jpg');
```