# How to save a figure in MATLAB from the command line?

Tags: matlab, save, figure

Is there a command in MATLAB which allows saving a figure in [FIG](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f9-34066.html) or [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) or both formats automatically?

Comment: actually this is my plot 

plot(x,y,'-bs','Linewidth',1.4,'Markersize',10)...
hold all
plot(Qx,Qy,'-.r*','Markersize',8)
title('Curve of the protein strand','FontSize',14);
legend('P Points (Input)','Q points (Output)','Location','North');

and I would like to save it automatically without waiting for the plot to appear !

but it seems that it is not possible because I cannot define a variable of multi curves on the same figure

Comment: possible duplicate of.. a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+save+figure

Answer (score 66):

Use [saveas](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/saveas.html):

```
h=figure;
plot(x,y,'-bs','Linewidth',1.4,'Markersize',10);
% ...
saveas(h,name,'fig')
saveas(h,name,'jpg')
```

This way, the figure is plotted, and automatically saved to '.jpg' and '.fig'. You don't need to wait for the plot to appear and click 'save as' in the menu. Way to go if you need to plot/save a lot of figures.

If you really do not want to let the plot appear (it has to be loaded anyway, can't avoid that, else there is also nothing to save), you can hide it:

```
h=figure('visible','off')
```

Comment: I tried it already, but it shows this error ??? Error: File: CurvePlotter.m Line: 3 Column: 1 Unexpected MATLAB expression. it is because of the hold all inside my plot !

Comment: and what is there at line3 in that file?
You know.. `hold all` is a command by itself, don't use it as `hold all plot(Qx,Qy,'-.r*','Markersize',8) ` but rather `hold all; plot(...)` Also: [learn to debug](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f10-60570.html)

Answer (score 23):

When using the saveas function the resolution isn't as good as when manually saving the figure with File-->Save As..., It's more recommended to use [hgexport](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgexport.html) instead, as follows:

```
hgexport(gcf, 'figure1.jpg', hgexport('factorystyle'), 'Format', 'jpeg');
```

This will do exactly as manually saving the figure.

source:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1PT49C/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-1PT49C

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can save it without it appearing, but just for saving in multiple formats use the *print* command. See the answer posted here: [Save an imagesc output in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146112/save-an-imagesc-output-in-matlab)

Comment: I tried it already, but it shows this error

??? Error: File: CurvePlotter.m Line: 3 Column: 1
Unexpected MATLAB expression.

it is because of the  hold all inside my plot !

Comment: @Abdullah I'm confused since you posted exactly the same comment to both answers. Do you get this error using the _print_ command or using _saveas_? Regardless of which one you get the error with, I have this code working: `x = 1:100;
y = rand(1,100);
Qx = x;
Qy = rand(1,100);

plot(x,y,'-bs','Linewidth',1.4,'Markersize',10)
hold all plot(Qx,Qy,'-.r*','Markersize',8) 
title('Curve of the protein strand','FontSize',14); 
legend('P Points (Input)','Q points (Output)','Location','North'); 
print(gcf, '-djpeg99',  num2str(1));
hold`

Comment: I lloked in this page, but I didn't find how to save it in ".fig" format 
http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/print.html

Comment: ok .. I got it !

plot(x,y,'-bs','Linewidth',1.4,'Markersize',10)
hold all 
plot(Qx,Qy,'-.r*','Markersize',8)
title('Curve of the protein strand','FontSize',14); 
legend('P Points (Input)','Q points (Output)','Location','North');
 print(gcf, '-djpeg99', num2str(1));
 saveas(gcf,'1');

you get out 2 outputs, one as jpg and the other as .fig

but still I don't understand what does 'gcf' mean ???

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save it as .fig file, hgsave is the function in Matlab R2012a.
In later versions, savefig may also work.

Answer (score 0):

`imwrite(A,filename)` writes image data A to the file specified by filename, inferring the file format from the extension

Answer (score 0):

These days (May 2017), MATLAB still suffer from a robust method to export figures, especially in GNU/Linux systems when exporting figures in batch mode. The best option is to use the extension [export_fig](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig)

Just download the source code from Github and use it:

```
plot(cos(linspace(0, 7, 1000)));
set(gcf, 'Position', [100 100 150 150]);
export_fig test2.png
```

Answer (score -2):

try 
plot(var);
saveFigure('title');
it will save as a jpeg automatically

Comment: there isn't any function named like that

Comment: Try it and you will see that yes there is one, although 'savefig' is advised by a warning message.

Comment: There is one indeed... like Thom said. but I need to correct myself you will need to do saveFigure('title.jpg'); but I also saw savefig [online](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html#bt0w30o-1_1)...

Comment: That's `savefig` not `saveFigure`.